# How to reference two DTD files in the DOCTYPE declaration in an XML document?

Tags: xml

Is it possible to reference ***two DTD*** files in the *DOCTYPE* declaration in an
XML document?

I am a beginner and trying to use elements from the ***two DTD*** files so that I can then add namespace attribute to uniquely identify the elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Book xmlns="http://www.xmlws101.com/xmlns/book">
   <Title>Professional ASP.NET 2.0</Title>
   <Price>49.99</Price>
   <Year>2005</Year>
</Book>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Author xmlns="http://www.xmlws101.com/xmlns/author">
   <Title>Mr.</Title>
   <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
   <LastName>Evjen</LastName>
</Author>
```

Secondly, I just don't understand how will I be able to use the two `<Title>` tags in a single XML document?

The author says:
A conflict exists with the `<Title>` tag. If you are using both these XML files, you might be able to tell the difference between the tags by just glancing at them; but computers are unable to decipher the difference between two tags with the same name.

The solution to this problem is to give the tag an identifier that enables the computer to tell the difference between the two tags. Do this is by using the XML namespace attribute, xmlns.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to reference two DTD files in the DOCTYPE declaration in an XML document?

No.

> I am a beginner and trying to use elements from the two DTD files so that I can then add namespace attribute to uniquely identify the elements.

You'll need to reference a single DTD file.

It can include other DTDs, although I believe they will need to be designed to be included that way in the first place (see [modular XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/) for am example).

> Secondly, I just don't understand how will I be able to use the two `<Title>` tags in a single XML document?

You'll need to put them into a different [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). Then your document will use the `xmlns` attribute to describe which namespace each element is from.

Comment: I upvoted you. I do understand the concept of namespaces to resolve similar naming conflicts. But then since I will be refencing a single DTD, all the elements must be unique themselves then why the need to have namespace. I am pretty confused when they(authors) says If these XML fragments were added together, there would be a name conflict. First of all I just don't understand this... how will I add  XML fragments together since I cant reference two DTDs.

Comment: See the [XHTML+RDF DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-rdfa/#a_xhtmlrdfa_dtd) which puts the namespace short name in the DTD. (DTDs play very poorly with mixed namespace XML documents, which is why people usually use schemas instead).

Comment: When the author puts that attribute xmlns onto an element, does I need to declare this xmlns explicitly in the dtd?

Comment: I believe so. As I said, DTDs are rubbish at namespaces.